# How to display N number of Movies the staffs has and the N number of Staffs the Movies has in Django Rest-framework api

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm Creating a site where I Have *models.py* like below

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    staff_name = models.CharField("Staff Name", max_length=25)
    staff_dob = models.DateField("Staff Date of Birth", help_text="Staff Born Date")
    staff_gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER, help_text="Staff's Gender")
    staff_about = models.TextField("About the Staff")
    staff_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="Anime/Staff/images/")

class Movies(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(help_text="Author name of the movie", max_length=50)
    country_of_origin = models.CharField("Country Of Origin", max_length=20)
    start_date = models.DateField("Start Date")
    end_date = models.DateField("End date")
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=RELEASE_STATUS, help_text="Current status of the movie")
    staffs = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

**I want to display N number of Movies the Staffs have and N number of Staffs the Movie have.**

I'm new to Django and rest_framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on your models, a movie can only have one staff

Comment: You might want to change that to ManyToManyField if you want multiple staff per movie, and multiple movies per staff

Comment: Yeah i got it from your words, but i have to declare one side only?

Comment: Yes only one side. You can find the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)